# JSP - Inline JS Compression / Minification

Tags: jsp, minify, google-closure-compiler, yui-compressor, html-compression

We have an web application written in Java which has around 150 JSP files. Unfortunately, each of these JSP files contains inline JS code written in it. I'm trying to compress these file to improve the performance.

Currently I'm using HTMLCompressor which just compresses the HTML part of the file, but doesn't minify the scripts written inline. Though the HTMLCompressor provides an option to compress the inline scripts also, it fails to handle the JSP condition tags written within my script tag. I tried changing the compressor from YUI to Google Closure, but the problem remains as is.

Is there is a way to handle this scenario or kindly suggest if there are any other compression tools which lets me compress the JSP/HTML along with the inline scripts written in this.

Note: Moving scripts to separate JS file is one of the optimization I can think as of now, however this is not an option for me since the number of JSP files are huge and time is an constraint.

Please feel free to correct if my thought process itself is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If your pages aren't using a strict CSP banning eval. One solution would be to wrap your expressions in evals:

var x = eval("... JSP substitution here ... ");

Depending on what you are providing the pages, this may work but as you can provide any arbitrary text it is easy to envision cases where this won't work.